# Angle function $\theta(t)=\theta_0+\int_0 ^t (fg'-gf') du$

Tags: differential-geometry

this problem is from Elementary Differential Geometry 2/e (Barrett O'Neill)

> let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable real-valued functions on an interval $I\subset\mathbb R$. Suppose that $f^2+g^2=1$  and that $\theta_0$ is a number such that $f(0)=\cos\theta_0$, $g(0)=\sin\theta_0$. If $\theta$ is the function such that
> $$\theta(t)=\theta_0 + \int_0 ^t (fg'-gf')du$$
> prove that  $$f=\cos\theta$$ $$g=\sin\theta$$
> HINT : It is enough to show that $(f-\cos\theta)^2+(g-\sin\theta)^2=0$.

After a bit of complicate calculation, I was able to show that

$\frac d {dt} ( (f-\cos\theta)^2+(g-\sin\theta)^2)=-(ff'+gg')(f\cos\theta+g\sin\theta)=0\quad(\because f^2+g^2=1)$

but it only implies that $$(f-\cos\theta)^2+(g-\sin\theta)^2=k$$
while $k$ is a constant. How can I prove $k=0$?

Comment: Check what happens at $\theta(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have not yet used that $f(0) = \cos \theta_0$ and that $g(0) = \sin \theta_0$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/859877)

Comment: It provides, as claimed, a hint (and a substantial one) to the very question asked, namely "How can I prove $k = 0$." It has nothing to do with clarifications.